# Why does gsub behave differently on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I wasn't able to test on all Linux distro, but `gsub` seems to behave differently when on Ubuntu :

```
url <- "http://thinkr.fr/"
gsub("(.*)/", "\\1", url) 

#Returns

# on mac, Windows, CentOS
[1] "http://thinkr.fr" 

# On Ubuntu (plain and Mint) 
[1] "http:/thinkr.fr"
```

Ubuntu returns `http:/` where all the others return `http://`.

Any idea why?

Here is the session info for the Linux Mint that produces the second output :

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.3.0 tidyr_0.8.0   dplyr_0.7.4   purrr_0.2.4   glue_1.2.0    attempt_0.2.0
[7] jsonlite_1.5  httr_1.3.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.16     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.2.2         magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.2.1    
 [6] stringi_1.1.7    rlang_0.2.0      curl_3.0         neo4r_0.0.0.9000 bindrcpp_0.2    
[11] tools_3.4.3      igraph_1.2.1     yaml_2.1.17      compiler_3.4.3   pkgconfig_2.0.1 
[16] tidyselect_0.2.4 bindr_0.1        tibble_1.4.2
```

[image]

```
> extSoftVersion()
                               zlib                               bzlib 
                            "1.2.8"                "1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010" 
                                 xz                                PCRE 
                       "5.1.0alpha"                   "8.38 2015-11-23" 
                                ICU                                 TRE 
                                 ""           "TRE 0.8.0 R_fixes (BSD)" 
                              iconv                            readline 
                       "glibc 2.23"                               "6.3" 
                               BLAS 
"/usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0" 
> pcre_config()
             UTF-8 Unicode properties                JIT              stack 
              TRUE               TRUE               TRUE               TRUE
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu/WSL I get the first output, not the second.

Comment: On linux mint it gives me the first output (the expected on I guess)

Comment: On debian i get the first one too.

Comment: On CentOS 7, I get the first one.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I have the second one.

Comment: On Elementary OS Loki, R 3.4.4, I get the first one.

Comment: You are testing against different strings, so there is no *real* programming issue here. The question is off-topic (typo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the image you uploaded showing your issue you don't have the "/" at the end of your string so it captures until the last "/" which is just the second slash in http://

So the issue is that you used a different input.

Comment: Side note it send like your goal is to remove the / if there is one at the end? If so you could use gsub("/$","",url) instead.

Comment: Yep, that's what I went for in the end to prevent this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Dason Or `sub("/$","",url)` as we're replacing single occurrence.